# Create a database if is needed in rethinkdb

Tags: javascript, node.js, rethinkdb

This is my very first interaction with rethinkdb, it looks pretty good but i'm having some problems...

The idea is simple: create a database if is not created yet.

The code is simple, or well, the idea of code:

```
module.exports = function(r, config) {
  var connection = null;

  r.connect(config.rdb, function(err, conn) {
    if (err) throw err
      connection = conn;
  });

  r.dbList()
    .contains('semestres')
    .do(function(dbExists) {
      return r.branch(
        dbExists,
        { created: 0 },
        r.dbCreate('semestres')
      );
    })
    .run(connection, function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
};
```

So, this just creates a connection and asign the connection to the variable, then checks if a database "semestres" exists, if it exists, it does nothing,  else, create it.

But not, i get this error when run the server:

```
Unhandled rejection RqlDriverError: First argument to `run` must be an open connection.
    at new RqlDriverError (/home/nano/Dev/semestres/node_modules/rethinkdb/errors.js:14:13)
    at FunCall.TermBase.run (/home/nano/Dev/semestres/node_modules/rethinkdb/ast.js:129:29)
    at module.exports (/home/nano/Dev/semestres/config/database.js:20:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nano/Dev/semestres/server.js:10:29)
    at Module._compile (module.js:428:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:446:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:469:10)
    at startup (node.js:124:18)
    at node.js:882:3
```

So, how i can make this type of operations in rethinkdb?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because this is JavaScript and the code is asynchronous, your `dbList` query does not have access to your `connection` variable. You need to put your `dbList` code **inside** the connect callback.

```
module.exports = function(r, config) {
  var connection = null;

  r.connect(config.rdb, function(err, conn) {
    if (err) throw err
      connection = conn;
      r.dbList()
        .contains('semestres')
        .do(function(dbExists) {
          return r.branch(
            dbExists,
            { created: 0 },
            r.dbCreate('semestres')
          );
        })
        .run(connection, function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
        });
    };
  });
```

This has nothing to do with RethinkDB itself, but with the way scoping works in JavaScript.

Comment: So ugly, so so ugly... why oh why doesn't RethinkDB use a connection pool its what people want in 90% of cases. Having to handle low level crap like this is what caused them to go belly up :/

Comment: `rethinkdb-dash` (a JS driver for RethinkDB) has connection pooling out of the box. The issue this solves is completely irrelevant to connection pooling, because this is about DB creation, not connection pooling. If you're concerned about the aesthetics of this code, there are other way this could be accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

as we know JavaScript is asynchronous, better use promises or callbacks

```
import r from 'rethinkdb'
import config from '../config/rethinkDb/dbConfig'
let c = (callback) => { r.connect(config, (err, conn) => { callback(conn) }) }

export function showMenu(callback) {
    c((conn) => {
        r.table('menus').run(conn, function(err, res) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.toArray(function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                callback(result);
            });
        });
    })

}

export function showMenu(callback) {\....
```